# Можно ли указывать размеры объектов в процентном соотношении от экрана?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли указывать размеры (длина, ширина) различных объектов в процентном соотношении, в зависимости от размеров экрана (ну или от материнского объекта)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно. Причём, несколькими способами.

1. Рекомендуемый гуглом [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

Первый способ:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <Button
         android:text="Button"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/button"
         app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
         app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Второй способ:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.constraint.Guideline
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".15"
         android:orientation="vertical"/>

     <android.support.constraint.Guideline
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".85"
         android:orientation="vertical"/>

     <android.support.constraint.Guideline
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".15"
         android:orientation="horizontal"/>

     <android.support.constraint.Guideline
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".85"
         android:orientation="horizontal"/>

     <Button
         android:text="Button"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:id="@+id/button"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. С использованием веса (при активном использовании во множестве вложенных элементов снижает производительность):

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <Space
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:weight="1" />

     <Button
         android:text="Button"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:weight="1" />

     <Space
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. Не рекомендованный и устаревший [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: с версии 1.1 с процентами в `ConstraintLayout` все стало [намного проще](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#match_constraint-dimensions--added-in-1.1-). Появились атрибуты для вложенных виджетов `layout_constraintWidth_percent`/`layout_constraintHeight_percent` . Использовать Guideline для этих целей уже не требуется.

Comment: @pavlofff, хм, действительно) Добавил в ответ